# Scrapy/Splash Select option

Tags: scrapy, splash-screen, scrapy-splash

I am really starting to get frustrated with how scrapy splash works. I do not understand how to select a value and take a screenshot after the value is selected. Here is my code so far that doesnt work....

the scraping url: https://www.chewy.com/kong-classic-dog-toy-large/dp/38485

**large** is selected but I would like to select **small** in this case and take a screenshot afterwards.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest, SplashFormRequest
from scrapy import FormRequest, Selector


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'https://www.chewy.com/kong-classic-dog-toy-large/dp/38485',
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    # Gets HTML and saves to file
    def parse(self, response):
        page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        filename = 'quotes-%s.html' % page
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
        self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)

        yield FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formname='sku-selector',
            formdata={
                '15949': 'Small', 
            }
        )

        with open('request.png', 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```

Comment: Where are you using `SplashRequest`?

Comment: I have no clue what I am using :(